# Display placeholder instead of 0 when binding empty fields of numbers in MVC5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am working on edit in `MVC 5` with `API` `Controllers`. When user presses edit, a model with values fetched from db will be passed. However when adding a new data, empty model will be passed with following code

```
var Model = {
    Id: '',
    Type: ''
}
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Control")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { model: Model },
    success: function (data) {
    }
```

My web controller

```
public ActionResult Add(Model model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

Now when I try to add the values, all the fields with `string` type will show placeholder but `integers` will show 0 instead of placeholder. I know its because I have passed empty field for numbers in my model but I need a workaround such that when empty numbers are passed it shows placeholder instead of displaying 0 using `javascript` or `jquery`

Comment: Could you show how your `Model` class looks like? If you want to know if a value is not set, you have to make the property of type `int?`/`Nullable<int>` instead of `int`. This allows the value to be null, which indicates a not set value.

Comment: My `Model` is of format `public int id {get; set;}` format. I will try your suggestion

Comment: It is working thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to model binding to avoid 0 as default to integer type , please user null able integer value

```
 public int? Count { get; set; }
```

This will assign as null to integer property rather than zero when you post model from java script or jquery as black or empty.